# Connection Reset SoapUI & (.svc vs .asmx)

Tags: web-services, wcf, soapui, asmx

I am encountering some odd behavior, with some research I have tried to apply many of the different ideas such as forcing https.protocols of TLSv1 or SSLv3 and trying to check IIS configuration vs SoapUI configuration, I am truly stumped.

Essentially the issue is that when connecting to a WCF service hosted on our DEV servers, I am receiving a `java.netSocketException: Connection reset` error. The WCF host extension is .svc, however if I simply change to .asmx I do not have this issue. The other thing I noticed is that the size of the result set has an upper limitation. The result set I am failing to bring back should be roughly 6.5MB, but am only able to bring back a result set less than 500kB.

I have used Fiddler to trace the traffic and received a 504 error. I have check IIS settings but have not found anything that seems out of the ordinary.

Below is my error log from SoapUI.

```
ERROR [errorlog] java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:149)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:264)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingSessionInputBuffer.readLine(LoggingSessionInputBuffer.java:115)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:98)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:252)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:281)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:247)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:219)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpClientSupport.java:147)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:633)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:454)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport$Helper.execute(HttpClientSupport.java:233)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport.execute(HttpClientSupport.java:323)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.submitRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:297)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.sendRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:227)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit.run(WsdlSubmit.java:119)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there were no issues with hitting the webservices using the ASMX uri, the SVC uri required a tag added to the web.config. This was a result of the .SVC service having a default item limit of 65538.

`<dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>`

`<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior> 
    </serviceBehaviors>
 </behaviors>`